Is there a fundamental bug in the Win32 API when it comes to producing the wrong messagebox beep?
I've been experimenting with popping up an error messagebox upon hitting enter in a textbox, and I think I've come up against a very low-level Win32 bug.  Given a very minimalist C# .NET 9 WinForms program, the two files below make up the only form, Form1.
When I click button1, I get an error messagebox with the correct "error" chime.  When I type a character in textBox1, I also get an error messagebox with the correct "error" chime.  However, when I hit Enter in textBox2, I get an error messagebox with the wrong 'normal' Windows beep sound.  The weird thing is that if I just use e.SuppressKeyPress = true; I get silence, but if I actually display a messagebox it gives the wrong beep.  It's like the Win32 API is somehow detecting that Enter was pressed and using that to determine what beep to play, instead of using the MessageBoxIcon.Error passed in, which is what it normally seems to use.
Is this a fundamental issue with Win32 that can't be worked around?  Or is there some way to get it to play the correct "error" beep when you hit Enter in textBox2?
Code:
Form1.cs
namespace SoundTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            MessageBox.Show("Test error", "Test error caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            MessageBox.Show("Test error", "Test error caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            MessageBox.Show("Test error", "Test error caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            // ^ commenting this out makes things silent.  but having the message box makes it play the wrong beep
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
}

Form1.Designer.cs
namespace SoundTest
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            button1 = new Button();
            textBox1 = new TextBox();
            textBox2 = new TextBox();
            SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            button1.Location = new Point(331, 46);
            button1.Name = "button1";
            button1.Size = new Size(75, 23);
            button1.TabIndex = 0;
            button1.Text = "button1";
            button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            button1.Click += button1_Click;
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            textBox1.Location = new Point(334, 213);
            textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            textBox1.Size = new Size(100, 23);
            textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            textBox2.Location = new Point(401, 333);
            textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            textBox2.Size = new Size(100, 23);
            textBox2.TabIndex = 2;
            textBox2.KeyDown += textBox2_KeyDown;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(7F, 15F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(800, 450);
            Controls.Add(textBox2);
            Controls.Add(textBox1);
            Controls.Add(button1);
            Name = "Form1";
            Text = "Form1";
            ResumeLayout(false);
            PerformLayout();
        }

        #endregion

        private Button button1;
        private TextBox textBox1;
        private TextBox textBox2;
    }
}


Dot net 9 is fres out and we find even in dor net 4.8 still many unfixed bugs. As long you don't need Dot net 9 functions stick to Dot net 8 till some time has passed and the worst is fixed

I don't think this is a .NET 9 thing, though.  I used source link support to debug it and the erroneous sound happened when a call was made into Win32.  Everything I could see in the C# source looked fine.  It wasn't playing any sounds at all, let alone an erroneous one.

try it in in Dot net 8 and seven and see if is the same.

e.SuppressKeyPress = true; BeginInvoke(()=> MessageBox.Show(...)); -- Careful when presenting modal dialog from event handlers

@Charlieface You simply defer the execution of blocking code, so the modal dialog is shown after the code in the event handler has completed. The same can be tested with Thread.Sleep(): add a Click event handler to a Button and add button1.Enabled = false; Thread.Sleep(2000); new Form().Show(); button1.Enabled = true;. Now, click the Button repeatedly. Then make the handler async and replace Thread.Sleep() with await Task.Delay() (which, in the end, is a BeginInvoke() call)

I suspect the issue is a combination of multiple things coming together: SuppressKeyPress=true is used by WinForms to run a PeekMessage loop to remove pending WM_CHAR etc messages, and PeekMessage at the same time dispatches non-queued messages. One of those non-queued messages has been placed by the creation of the message box, and is used by WinApi to actually play the sound using PlaySound. But the sound for the Enter is probably played by the WM_KEYDOWN/UP handlers, so is not removed.

So ends up that both sounds are played instantaneously, with one of them overriding. Setting AcceptsReturn = true on the textbox might help, or otherwise suppressing the KeyUp event.

@Charlieface Run a nested message loop. The event handler is blocked until the modal dialog returns. That's when you experience those funny reentrancy things (as the experiment with the Button should demonstrate)

@Jimi Well yeah, that's the point of a synchronous event handler: you don't expect the code following the message box to be executed until the box returns (useful if you want a yes/no result).

@Charlieface In .NET 9, WinForms is going to get async, awaitable, versions of the methods that present the dialogs. Not hard to guess why that is

I'm actually using .NET 9.  What methods do I need to use?

I'm referring to the new ShowDialogAsync  (also the ShowAsync() counterpart), which applies to Forms. With a MessageBox, you still need to BeginInvoke() it (as the most straightforward tool)

It gives me "'System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowAsync' is for evaluation purposes only and is subject to change or removal in future updates." when I try to use it.  Doesn't seem like a great idea.

@Jimi Using BeginInvoke did indeed fix the sound made by the popup but I have no idea why.  Could you post it as an answer giving a full explanation of why it's required?  I thought Invoke was for when you had a non-UI thread that needed to trigger the UI thread to do something, but in this case it's the UI thread running the event callback anyway.

That's because that piece of code has a Diagnostic attribute set. But the same code has been going around for quite a while, and it's implemented in the (almost) same way in some commercial frameworks. In the end, it's just [SynchronizationContext].Post() (which is still a BeginInvoke() call) + [TaskCompletionSource].SetResult(). Pretty safe and, overall, already tested -- You use Invoke() when you need synchronous behavior (i.e., you have to wait for the call to return), BeginInvoke() when you don't (or you just need to defer the execution, so the call is enqueued)
